# How do you show that Einstein's tensor simplifies to the unitary form in geometric algebra?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, clifford-algebra

In David Hestenes' [Gauge Theory Gravity paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10701-005-5828-y) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226117395_Gauge_Theory_Gravity_with_Geometric_Calculus)), he claims that

$$G^\beta = \tfrac{1}{2}(g^\beta \wedge g^\mu \wedge g^\nu) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)$$ in geometric algebra (specifically, spacetime algebra). This is the unitary form that I want to prove follows from the definition of $G^\beta$ and the left hand side of Einstein's equation below.

Einstein's equation is

$$ G(g_\nu) \equiv R(g_\nu) -\tfrac{1}{2}g_\nu R = \kappa T(g_\nu) $$

where the Ricci tensor is

$$R(g_\nu) = g^\mu \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)$$

and the scalar curvature is

$$R \equiv g^\nu \cdot R(g_\nu) = (g^\nu \wedge g^\mu) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)$$

[edit] Hestenes says that these are needed:

$$ a \cdot (b \wedge B) = a \cdot b B - b \wedge (a \cdot B) \quad \textrm{for grade(B)}\geq 2 $$

$$ a \cdot (b \cdot B) = (a \wedge b) \cdot B $$

Attempt:

\begin{aligned}
G^\beta &\equiv G(g^\beta) = R(g^\beta) -\tfrac{1}{2}g^\beta R \\
&= g^\mu \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g^\beta) - \tfrac{1}{2} g^\beta (g^\nu \wedge g^\mu) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) \\
&= (g^\mu g^\nu \cdot g^\beta) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) - \tfrac{1}{2} g^\beta \wedge ((g^\nu \wedge g^\mu) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)) \\
&= (g^\mu \wedge (g^\nu g^\beta- g^\nu \wedge g^\beta)) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) - \tfrac{1}{2} g^\beta \wedge ((g^\nu \wedge g^\mu) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)) 
\end{aligned}

I could not get the two terms into the common form of "$(trivector)\cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)$" to simplify further.

Attempt 2:

\begin{aligned}
G^\beta &\equiv G(g^\beta) = R(g^\beta) -\tfrac{1}{2}g^\beta R \\
&= g^\mu \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g^\beta) - \tfrac{1}{2} g^\beta (g^\nu \wedge g^\mu) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) \\
&= (g^\mu g^\nu \cdot g^\beta) \cdot R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu) - \tfrac{1}{2} g^\beta \wedge ((g^\nu \wedge g^\mu) \rfloor R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)) \\
&=  (g^\mu g^\nu \cdot g^\beta) \cdot R(...) - \tfrac{1}{2}((g^\beta \rfloor (g^\nu \wedge g^\mu)) \rfloor R(...) \\
&= (g^\mu g^\nu \cdot g^\beta - \tfrac{1}{2}(g^\beta \cdot g^\nu g^\mu - g^\nu g^\beta \cdot g^\mu) \rfloor R(...) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}(g^\mu g^\nu \cdot g^\beta + g^\nu g^\beta \cdot g^\mu) \rfloor R(...) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{4}(g^\mu g^\nu g^\beta + g^\mu g^\beta g^\nu + g^\nu g^\beta g^\mu + g^\nu g^\mu g^\beta) \rfloor R(g_\mu \wedge g_\nu)
\end{aligned}

Now it is getting closer to the definition of the wedge product between 3 vectors.